# what is the meaning of "*" in the following code?

Tags: lua

I'm playing with Lua https://www.lua.org/pil/1.html and saw the following example.

```
-- defines a factorial function
    function fact (n)
      if n == 0 then
        return 1
      else
        return n * fact(n-1)
      end
    end

    print("enter a number:")
    a = io.read("*number")        -- read a number
    print(fact(a))
```

I was wondering, what is the meaning of "*" in the line `a = io.read("*number")        -- read a number`?

Comment: Lua authors are frequently using `*` symbol in magic strings: `io.read"*a"`, `os.date"*t"`, `debug.getregistry()["FILE*"]`, `local *toclose x`.

Comment: So, what are exactly "magic strings"?

Comment: `io.read` takes a format string or number as an argument (or "arguments"). See [5.0](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.0/manual.html#5.6) or [5.3](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-file:read). There is no real meaning in that it's just a part of the format string, hence magic.